# Android - device is not compatible with this version

Tags: android, google-play

I have updated my apk into play store with request for more permissions. Some of the devices show "device is not compatible with this version" message.

manifest xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.blynq.app.multipaneplayer">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALWAYS_FINISH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_PROCESS_LIMIT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SIGNAL_PERSISTENT_PROCESSES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_READ" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_WRITE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SOCIAL_STREAM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_PROFILE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SOCIAL_STREAM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY"/>



    <application ...
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

gradle:

```
...
compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.blynq.app.multipaneplayer"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode VERSION_CODE
        versionName VERSION_NAME
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        multiDexEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 23
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

    }
...
```

I have following queries in this regard:

1. Does asking extra permissions make the app incompatible with device ? For ex: If device does not have a camera and I ask for camera permission, would it make the app incompatible ?
2. How can I fetch the precise reason why a particular app is incompatible in certain device ?
3. Would the use of renderscript library cause any related trouble ? Also, is it fine to have the renderscriptTargetApi more than the minSdkVersion ?

P.S :- 
sdkversion of devices on which I have tested - 19. 
I've requested for all possible permissions as this is a proprietary app, installed in plug pcs, no other app would be used in these devices.

Answer (score 1):

> Does asking extra permissions make the app incompatible with device ? For ex: If device does not have a camera and I ask for camera permission, would it make the app incompatible ?

Yes. If device don't having camera but you still add it in permission then for that device it become incompatible.

You can use it like

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" required="false"/>
```

> How can I fetch the precise reason why a particular app is incompatible in certain device ?

Try some test case removing permission and you can use GooglePlay **aplha** and **beta** version facility.

> Would the use of renderscript library cause any related trouble ? Also, is it fine to have the renderscriptTargetApi more than the targetSdkVersion ?

This is recommended that Library `minSdkVersion` version must not greater than the app minSdkVersion. `targetSdkVersion` can be higher than our app targetSdkVersion version.

Comment: Thankyou. Since I'm requesting for many permissions, how do I know which exact permissions are causing the trouble? Would google play store mention these somewhere in the console ?

Comment: Permission related to hardware cause the problem most. Like camera, Flashlight. Also some tablet dont have calling facility so asking for call, phone permission will make device not compatible.

Comment: Can I mention a permission to be optional ? I mean, if such provision is available, grant permission, else ignore.

Comment: you will also get list of devices removed in this version due to compatibility issue. Check that before upload

Comment: I don't think there is anything like optional. search for https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html